# What does auto mean in a return type, and when are explicit return types necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference, return-type-deduction

1. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax)

   What is the use of the keyword **`auto`**
   in this case (below) if not automatic type deduction?

   ```
   struct SomeStruct {
       auto func_name(int x, int y) -> int;
   };

   auto SomeStruct::func_name(int x, int y) -> int {return x + y; }
   ```
2. What are some of the situations one needs to **explicitly** have types?

Comment: You might notice that this syntax is *not* part of the "type inference" section on the Wiki page.

Comment: @Nicol Sorry, edited. Its on the Alternative_function_syntax section.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the trailing return type. `auto` is simply a placeholder that indicates that the return type comes later.

The reason for this is so that the parameter names can be used in computing the return type:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
auto add(L l, R r) -> decltype(l+r) { return l+r; }
```

The alternative is:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
decltype(std::declval<L>()+std::declval<R>())
add(L l, R r)
{ return l+r; }
```

It's likely that a future addition to the language will be to allow leaving out the trailing return type and instead using automatic type deduction as is permitted with lambdas.

```
template<typename L, typename R>
auto add(L l, R r) { return l+r; }
```

Comment: Indeed, GCC 4.8.0 supports automatic return type deduction with `-std=c++1y`.

Comment: Actually there are competing proposals (or intents to submit such proposals) to phase out the prefixed return type altogether in favour of trailing return types, in an effort to consolidate the syntax of function declarations with that of polymorphic lambdas, and allow automatic return type deduction. Have a look here: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/11/having-it-all-pythy-syntax/

Comment: That makes sense, so the **return type** is of type `decltype(l+r)` This too should worK, right?: `auto add(L l, R r) -> auto { return l+r; }`

Comment: @Ian Yes, although as far as I know the syntax would drop the redundant `-> auto` and if it’s a single statement, the `return` would ideally be superfluous as well, so that your example could (hopefully! one day) be written as `auto add(l, r) l + r;`